# how to give connection string in app.config file and how to call it

Tags: c#, connection-string

i used the following code in app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=162.1.6.4;Initial Catalog=Followon_SP;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and in form.cs

```
struct st
{

    public static SqlConnection con;
};
public Mainform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
       st.con = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connectionstring"].ToString());
    }
```

but i get the following error in connection open,

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this error

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this instead:

```
public Mainform()
{
    InitializeComponent();     

    // read out the .ConnectionString property - don't call .ToString() !!
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    st.con = new SqlConnection(cs);
}
```

Use the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` (not the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`), and then read out the connection string from the `.ConnectionString` property instead of calling `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: @csura: you need to use `ConfigurationManager.COnnectionStrings[...]` instead of `.AppSettings` - try again

Comment: now this error,Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Comment: @csura: now the mechanics work - now it's just your connection string info that's incomplete/invalid. The error is clear: you **cannot** use integrated security (`Integrated Security=SSPI`) - change your connection string to provide an explicit user name and password.

Comment: See [this web site here](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for a huge long list of samples of connection strings and what the individual options mean and how to use them

Answer (score 0):

Set new `SqlConnection(cs)` to your struct type of `con` field. Use it like this;

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
st.con = new SqlConnection(cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off using the Entity Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Add a new data model and VS will take care of all your config settings as long as you have the right username and password to enter in the wizard. Will make your development process a lot easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

Read Connection String using following code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = 
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0) {
    connString =
        rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
    if (connString != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"", connString.ConnectionString);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
}
```